# How do I merge an array of Observables with RxJS 6.x and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

For learning purposes, I'm creating a Node app that will need to take x RxJS observables from an array and combine into a single stream of events. I want to know when events occur in any observable, in any order (not in any sequence or full completion). I feel it should be in a single merged stream of events. Basically, the first event that comes through from any observable will complete.

For this, I felt merge() will do the trick. As merge doesn't take arrays directly as a parameter, I'm using reduce so far to help merge.

However, the end result is not an observable, but a function. I can't subscribe to it either. A simplified version of the code can be seen below.

How can I alter this Node 10.14.2, RxJS 6.4.x code to return an observable and not a "[function]" that I can tack a .subscribe() to?

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs');
const { merge } = require('rxjs/operators');

const observables = [
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello')),
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello')),
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello'))
];

const mergedObservables = observables.reduce((merged, observable) => {
    console.log(observable);
    return merge(merged, observable);
});

// outputs:
// Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }
// Observable { _isScalar: false, _subscribe: [Function] }

console.log(mergedObservables);

// outputs:
// [Function]

mergedObservables.subscribe();
// error:
// TypeError: mergedObservables.subscribe is not a function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT: You're importing the `merge` *operator* as opposed to the static `merge` function. The former operates on events from a source observable while the latter creates a new observable from one or more source observables. While the thought about the spread syntax below simplifies your code, it wasn't your real issue.

---

It appears [Node.js >= 5.0](https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-spread-syntax-for-iterable-objects-with-arrays--in-function-calls) supports the spread operator for arrays in function calls (you don't specify which version of Node.js you're using, though). The following should work if you're using a modern version of Node.js:

```js
const { Observable, merge } = require('rxjs')

const observables = [
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello')),
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello')),
    Observable.create(observer => observer.next('Hello'))
]

const mergedObservables = merge(...observables)
mergedObservables.subscribe(event => { console.log(event) })
```

Comment: This gets me closer. I do like the use of spread here. However, the results are the same with the sample you provided: "TypeError: mergedObservables.subscribe is not a function". I'm using Node version 10.14.2 and will correct in the question.

Comment: D'oh! That's because I'm using the _operator_ as opposed to the _function_ (the former acts on an observable's events, while the latter creates a new observable). I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This helped a lot. I didn't realize there was a merge operator AND function.